# Scala in IntelliJ error

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, intellij-13

I just downloaded the plug in for Scala in IntelliJ and have created a project but now have various errors I read that the problem can be that I am missing a library. But when I try and go to project structure -> dependencies to add a library I have no clue where in the files to look for a library. 
[image]
The errors are really simple but I can't seem to figure it out.

Any suggestions would be helpful :)

Answer (score 2):

[Here's](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/SCA/Getting+Started+with+IntelliJ+IDEA+Scala+Plugin) everything you need to properly set up Scala plugin in Intellij. Furthermore your code has several errors:

Are you sure you created a **Scala** project (when you did File->New->Project)? This looks to me like a **Java** project? That class file looks to me like a Java class not a Scala class (that's why you're getting compilation errors on `def` but not `public class`).

1) `value` is not defined anywhere, of course it will throw a compilation error

2) classes in Scala are by default `public`, you do not (cannot) mark them as such

Comment: It does say Counter.java on the screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

You can save yourself a lot of trouble by creating a simple SBT project that specifies all of your dependencies, etc. and then just pointing the IDE at that. Then when you change `build.sbt`, IntelliJ IDEA will notice that and update itself automatically. Plus, your `build.sbt` gets checked into your code base so that anyone you are collaborating with sees your changes to the dependencies. And the project can be built in batch mode using `sbt compile` and friends.

The following page talks about IntelliJ IDEA's "SBT Import" feature:

https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IntelliJIDEA/Getting+Started+with+SBT

Answer (score 0):

Scala source files end in `.scala`, not `.java`. Try renaming `Counter.java` to `Counter.scala`. This should improve things a lot.